# XML Namespace in Delphi

Tags: xml, delphi, namespaces

I am trying to access some Nodes in my XML File, but I cant get it working because i probably don't understand XML-Namepsaces in Delphi.

```
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
    <gesmes:Sender>
        <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
    </gesmes:Sender>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time="2018-01-18">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.2235"/>
            <Cube currency="JPY" rate="136.07"/>
            <Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
            <Cube currency="CZK" rate="25.365"/>
            <Cube currency="DKK" rate="7.4475"/>
            <Cube currency="GBP" rate="0.88208"/>
            <Cube currency="HUF" rate="308.51"/>
            <Cube currency="PLN" rate="4.1665"/>
            <Cube currency="RON" rate="4.6480"/>
            <Cube currency="SEK" rate="9.8305"/>
            <Cube currency="CHF" rate="1.1748"/>
            <Cube currency="NOK" rate="9.6013"/>
            <Cube currency="HRK" rate="7.4409"/>
            <Cube currency="RUB" rate="69.2126"/>
            <Cube currency="TRY" rate="4.6374"/>
            <Cube currency="AUD" rate="1.5311"/>
            <Cube currency="BRL" rate="3.9321"/>
            <Cube currency="CAD" rate="1.5229"/>
            <Cube currency="CNY" rate="7.8582"/>
            <Cube currency="HKD" rate="9.5648"/>
            <Cube currency="IDR" rate="16325.38"/>
            <Cube currency="ILS" rate="4.1950"/>
            <Cube currency="INR" rate="78.1210"/>
            <Cube currency="KRW" rate="1306.61"/>
            <Cube currency="MXN" rate="22.8174"/>
            <Cube currency="MYR" rate="4.8396"/>
            <Cube currency="NZD" rate="1.6759"/>
            <Cube currency="PHP" rate="62.068"/>
            <Cube currency="SGD" rate="1.6175"/>
            <Cube currency="THB" rate="39.054"/>
            <Cube currency="ZAR" rate="15.0035"/>
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

I tried to access the Cube Nodes like that:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Doc: IXMLDocument;
  Node: IXMLNode;
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  Doc := LoadXMLDocument('C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\test.xml');
  node := Doc.DocumentElement;

  ShowMessage(Node.ChildNodes['Cube']);
end;
```

I realized that my output is: "gesmes:Cube".
I don't think that is right... I excpected to get the the first "Cube" Node.
I am not sure how namespaces in Delphi work so it would be great if i could get some help here.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are passing an `IXMLNode` interface pointer to `ShowMessage()`, which expects a `string` instead.  So presumably, in your real code, you have actually done `ShowMessage(Node.ChildNodes['Cube'].NodeName);` instead.

Which indeed reports `'gesmes:Cube'`, which is not what you are expecting. The `Cube` you want is in the `http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref` namespace, which is different than the namespace of its parent `Envelope` (`http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01`).  So what actually happens is that `DocumentElement.ChildNodes['Cube']` tries to find a `Cube` in the `Envelope`'s namespace, finds no such element, so `TXMLDocument` **creates a new one** because the `doNodeAutoCreate` flag is enabled by default in the `Doc.Options` property.  That is the `Cube` that `DocumentElement.ChildNodes['Cube']` returns, not the `Cube` you want.

Because the `Envelope` and its immediate `Cube` child are in different namespaces, you can't use `ChildNodes['Cube']` on the `DocumentElement`, you have to use `ChildNodes.FindNode()` instead, specifying the `Cube`'s actual namespace:

```
Node := Doc.DocumentElement;
Node := Node.ChildNodes.FindNode('Cube', 'http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref');
```

The next `Cube` is in the same namespace as its parent `Cube`, so you can use `ChildNodes['Cube']` to get it:

```
Node := Node.ChildNodes['Cube'];
```

Then you can access the `time` attribute, if needed:

```
Node.Attributes['time']
```

And loop through the remaining child `Cube`s:

```
Node := Node.ChildNodes.First;
while Node <> nil do
begin
  if Node.LocalName = 'Cube' then
  begin
    // use Node.Attributes['currency'] and Node.Attributes['rate'] as needed...
  end;
  Node := Node.NextSibling;
end;
```

Here is the complete code:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Doc: IXMLDocument;
  Node: IXMLNode;
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Doc := LoadXMLDocument('C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\test.xml');
    try
      Node := Doc.DocumentElement;
      if Node = nil then ... // handle the error as needed...

      Node := Node.ChildNodes.FindNode('Cube', 'http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref');
      if Node = nil then ... // handle the error as needed...

      Node := Node.ChildNodes['Cube'];
      if Node = nil then ... // handle the error as needed...

      Node := Node.ChildNodes.First;
      while Node <> nil do
      begin
        if Node.LocalName = 'Cube' then
          sl.Add(Node.Attributes['currency'] + '=' + Node.Attributes['rate']);
        Node := Node.NextSibling;
      end;
    finally
      Node := nil;
      Doc := nil;
    end;

    // use sl as needed...

  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped. Even if its a little late now. The Project was paused for some time