# Get Value from a specific node xml file

Tags: delphi

How can i get the value 50.76 from this xml file, i can get that node.
[image]

i have tried reading the nodes

```
 XMLDoc.FileName := 'myfile.xml';
  XMLDoc.Active:=True;

  XMLDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.First.ChildNodes.FindNode('m:properties') ;
  ANode := StartItemNode;
  repeat
    STitle := ANode.ChildNodes['d:DollarSellRate m:type'].Text;

    ANode := ANode.NextSibling;
  until ANode = nil;
```

Comment: In future, please include any XML as text rather than a screen-shot - readers may wish to test any answer using the XML you are asking about.  -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ANode.ChildNodes['d:DollarSellRate m:type']` is not the correct way to refer to a node by name.  `m:type` is not part of the node name, it is an attribute of the `d:DollarSellRate` node.

In fact, you are not even drilling down through the parent/child hierarchy of nodes correctly at all.  In the statement:

`XMLDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.First.ChildNodes.FindNode('m:properties') ;`

The `XMLDoc.DocumentElement` property refers to the top-level `<feed>` node, and its `ChildNodes.First` property refers to its `<id>` child node, which in turn has no `<m:properties>` child node, so `FindNode()` will return `nil`.

Also, the XML nodes you are interested in are using multiple XML namespaces, so you have to take those into account when searching for nodes.  You can use `ChildNodes['name']` only when the child is in the same namespace as its parent node.  If the child is in a different namespace, you have to use `ChildNodes.FindNode('name', 'namespace')` instead. See [XML Namespace in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343141/) for more details.

Try something more like this:

```pascal
var
  Feed,
  Entry,
  Content,
  Props,
  DollarSellRate: IXMLNode;
  STitle: string;

...

XMLDoc.FileName := 'myfile.xml';
XMLDoc.Active := True;

Feed := XMLDoc.DocumentElement;

Entry := Feed.ChildNodes['entry'];
if Entry = nil then ... // handle the error as needed..

Content := Entry.ChildNodes['content'];
if Content = nil then ... // handle the error as needed..

Props := Content.ChildNodes.FindNode('properties', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata');
if Props = nil then ... // handle the error as needed..

DollarSellRate := Props.ChildNodes.FindNode('DollarSellRate', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices');
if DollarSellRate = nil then ... // handle the error as needed..

STitle := DollarSellRate.Text;
```

Answer (score -2):

I got the value with this code

```
  Feed := XMLDoc.DocumentElement;
  Entry := Feed.ChildNodes['entry'];
  Content := Entry.ChildNodes['content'].ChildNodes[0];
  Result := StrToFloat (Content.ChildValues[5]);
```

Comment: hi, your code is not working, you can get the xml file from the  url and test https://www.popularenlinea.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Rates')/items